# Content inside zip file

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to use zippackage class to know about the content in .zip file?
for ex to know the type of file inside this zip file.

Comment: You know that not all .ZIP files are packages?

Answer (score 4):

Once you open the .zip file, you can use the [`GetParts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.package.getparts.aspx) method to get a collection of all the files inside the .zip. See the [`PackagePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.packagepart.aspx) class.

Comment: @jammkie same - did you even look at the linked articles?

Answer (score 0):

http://sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/ is a good zip library for CSharp.

Although, you might just want to use something like the `DeflateStream` class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) which provides a compressed stream and doesn't require dealing with the complexities of an archive that handles multiple files.